# Ansible: 'regex_replace' removing every character starting with "@"

Tags: ansible

I have following registered variable with `stdout` and I want to remove every character starting with "@".

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "wazuh@4.3.10-4311"
    ]
}
```

Example: `wazuh@4.3.10-4311` should become `wazuh`.

Answer (score 1):

> remove every character after "@"

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_string: wazuh@4.3.10-4311
  tasks:  
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ my_string | regex_replace('@.*', '') }}"
```

Provides:

`wazuh`

Answer (score 1):

One could also look at the use case as just interested in the left part of the `@`
delimitered string.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    my_string: wazuh@4.3.10-4311

  tasks:

  # For Ansible v2.9 and later
  - name: Use of Python string method
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_string.split('@') | first }}"
```

So not removing the part behind but only deliver the part before.

```yaml
  # For Ansible v2.10 and later
  - name: Show left part with filter
    debug:
      msg: "{{ my_string | split('@') | first }}"
```

Comment: for ansible 2.9 doesn't recognize the "split"

Comment: It does, but in the Python way `"{{ my_string.split('@') | first }}"`. And there are more Python methods possible for strings ...

Comment: i need a solution regex that will work with all ansible versions..

Comment: `"{{ my_string.split('@') | first }}"` will work with all Ansible versions. Why it has to be regex?

Comment: doesn't work .. "fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'split'\n\nThe error appears to be in .. "

Comment: In an Ansible v2.9 setup I am not able to reproduce the error message. There it just work.

Answer (score 0):

Also this solution it's working:

```
regex_replace('@.*$','')
```